# Can I get progress towards A Matter of Perspective when I play with others?

Tags: achievements, dungeon-defenders

The achievement requirement for **A Matter of Perspective** is `Saw all four Hero endings`. I saw the Huntress ending last night, and my friends saw that one as well.

If I play the games with my friends when they deal the killing blow with a different class, will I get progress towards this achievement, or do I actually have to beat the campaign with different characters myself?

Comment: Whoever deals the final blow is the ending you'll see - so it doesn't matter what class the host is (unless the host dealt the final blow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question directly, if you are in a group with friends and they get a killing blow with a different class it **will** count towards your individual achievement since you will be seeing the ending based on the person getting the killing blow.